# error executing "/tmp/terraform_1843617083.sh": Process exited with status 100

Tags: ansible, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to connect to GCP compute instance for installing ansible on the VM . My goal is to run the playbook for installing and configuration and i am trying this as a initial phase.

. But failing and getting error

error executing "/tmp/terraform_1843617083.sh": Process exited with status 100**`**

This is my terraform code

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "my_server" {
  name         = "my-gcp-server"
  machine_type = "n1-standard-1"
  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image= "ubuntu-1604-lts"
    }
  }
     
  network_interface {
    network = "default"
    access_config {}
   }
   
provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = ["sudo apt-get install ansible"]

    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = "username"
      timeout = "500s"
      private_key = "${file("~/.ssh/id_rsa")}"
      host = "${google_compute_instance.my_server.network_interface.0.access_config.0.nat_ip}"
    }
  }

}
 output "ip" {
  value ="${google_compute_instance.my_server.network_interface.0.access_config.0.nat_ip}"
}
```

LOGS

```
oogle_compute_instance.my_server: Creating...
google_compute_instance.my_server: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
google_compute_instance.my_server: Provisioning with 'remote-exec'...
google_compute_instance.my_server (remote-exec): Connecting to remote host via SSH...
google_compute_instance.my_server (remote-exec):   Host: 34.71.118.182
google_compute_instance.my_server (remote-exec):   User: username
google_compute_instance.my_server (remote-exec):   Password: false
google_compute_instance.my_server (remote-exec):   Private key: true
google_compute_instance.my_server (remote-exec):   Certificate: false
google_compute_instance.my_server (remote-exec):   SSH Agent: false
google_compute_instance.my_server (remote-exec):   Checking Host Key: false
google_compute_instance.my_server: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
google_compute_instance.my_server (remote-exec): Connecting to remote host via SSH...
google_compute_instance.my_server (remote-exec):   Host: 34.71.118.182
google_compute_instance.my_server (remote-exec):   User: aravind
google_compute_instance.my_server (remote-exec):   Password: false
google_compute_instance.my_server (remote-exec):   Private key: true
google_compute_instance.my_server (remote-exec):   Certificate: false
google_compute_instance.my_server (remote-exec):   SSH Agent: false
google_compute_instance.my_server (remote-exec):   Checking Host Key: false
google_compute_instance.my_server (remote-exec): Connected!
google_compute_instance.my_server: Still creating... [30s elapsed]
google_compute_instance.my_server (remote-exec): Reading package lists... 0%
google_compute_instance.my_server (remote-exec): Reading package lists... 100%
google_compute_instance.my_server (remote-exec): Reading package lists... Done
google_compute_instance.my_server (remote-exec): Building dependency tree... 0%
google_compute_instance.my_server (remote-exec): Building dependency tree... 0%
google_compute_instance.my_server (remote-exec): Building dependency tree... 50%
google_compute_instance.my_server (remote-exec): Building dependency tree... 50%
google_compute_instance.my_server (remote-exec): Building dependency tree
google_compute_instance.my_server (remote-exec): Reading state information... 0%
google_compute_instance.my_server (remote-exec): Reading state information... 5%
google_compute_instance.my_server (remote-exec): Reading state information... Done


Error: error executing "/tmp/terraform_1843617083.sh": Process exited with status 100
```

Comment: Try to add -y to your apt-get and see if it resolves your problem.
inline = ["sudo apt-get install ansible -y"]